# How can I override Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement?

Tags: magento2, override-model

I need to override below from AccountManagement:

```
public function authenticate($username, $password)
{
    try {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
    }

    $customerId = $customer->getId();
    if ($this->getAuthentication()->isLocked($customerId)) {
        throw new UserLockedException(__('The account is locked.'));
    }
    try {
        $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $password);
        // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Exceptions.ThrowCatch
    } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
    }
    if ($customer->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired($customer)) {
        throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__("This account isn't confirmed. Verify and try again."));
    }

    $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData($customer);
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'customer_customer_authenticated',
        ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $password]
    );

    $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $customer]);

    return $customer;
}
```

I've tried preference & plugin, but non of these work. Even though override the whole model is worked, but it start giving me an error when authenticate.

Any help will appreciate...

Using Plugin

1. di.xml

   ```
   <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
       <plugin name="accountmanagement" type="MyModule\vendor\Plugin\Model\AccountManagement" sortOrder="1" />
   <type>
   ```
2. Model\AccountManagement

   ```
   namespace MyModule\vendor\Plugin\Model;


   class AccountManagement
   {
    public function authenticate($username, $password)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login'));
        }

        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        if ($this->getAuthentication()->isLocked($customerId)) {
            throw new UserLockedException(__('The account is locked.'));
        }
        try {
            $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $password);
            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Exceptions.ThrowCatch
        } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid password'));
        }
        if ($customer->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired($customer)) {
            throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__("This account isn't confirmed. Verify and try again."));
        }

        $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData($customer);
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'customer_customer_authenticated',
            ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $password]
        );

        $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $customer]);

        return $customer;
    }
   ?>
   ```

Using Preference

1. di.xml

   ```
   <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="MyModule\vendor\Model\AccountManagement" />
   ```

2.Model\AccountManagement

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Mymodule\vendor\Model\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\customerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\customerRegistry;
use Magento\Customer\Model\accountConfirmation;
use Magento\Customer\Model\addressRegistry;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\View as CustomerViewHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share as ConfigShare;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as CustomerModel;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\CredentialsValidator;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Validator;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Backend;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory as ObjectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface as Encryptor;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\Helper\Security;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\ExpiredException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InputMismatchException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InvalidTransitionException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;
use Magento\Framework\Intl\DateTimeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils as StringHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as PsrLogger;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement as CoreManage;
/**
 * Handle various customer account actions
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CookieAndSessionMisuse)
 */
class AccountManagement extends CoreManage
{
    /**
     * Configuration paths for email templates and identities
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_template';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_REGISTER_NO_PASSWORD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_no_password_template';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY = 'customer/create_account/email_identity';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_REMIND_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/password/remind_email_template';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/password/forgot_email_template';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY = 'customer/password/forgot_email_identity';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     * @see AccountConfirmation::XML_PATH_IS_CONFIRM
     */
    const XML_PATH_IS_CONFIRM = 'customer/create_account/confirm';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_confirmation_template';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customer/create_account/email_confirmed_template';

    /**
     * Constants for the type of new account email to be sent
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    const NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED = 'registered';

    /**
     * Welcome email, when password setting is required
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    const NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NO_PASSWORD = 'registered_no_password';

    /**
     * Welcome email, when confirmation is enabled
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    const NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = 'confirmation';

    /**
     * Confirmation email, when account is confirmed
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    const NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMED = 'confirmed';

    /**
     * Constants for types of emails to send out.
     * pdl:
     * forgot, remind, reset email templates
     */
    const EMAIL_REMINDER = 'email_reminder';

    const EMAIL_RESET = 'email_reset';

    /**
     * Configuration path to customer password minimum length
     */
    const XML_PATH_MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 'customer/password/minimum_password_length';

    /**
     * Configuration path to customer password required character classes number
     */
    const XML_PATH_REQUIRED_CHARACTER_CLASSES_NUMBER = 'customer/password/required_character_classes_number';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const XML_PATH_RESET_PASSWORD_TEMPLATE = 'customer/password/reset_password_template';

    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;

    /**
     * @var CustomerFactory
     */
    private $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $validationResultsDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $eventManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var Random
     */
    private $mathRandom;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $validator;

    /**
     * @var AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $addressRepository;

    /**
     * @var CustomerMetadataInterface
     */
    private $customerMetadataService;

    /**
     * @var PsrLogger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var Encryptor
     */
    private $encryptor;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRegistry
     */
    private $customerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var ConfigShare
     */
    private $configShare;

    /**
     * @var StringHelper
     */
    protected $stringHelper;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $sessionManager;

    /**
     * @var SaveHandlerInterface
     */
    private $saveHandler;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $visitorCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var DataObjectProcessor
     */
    protected $dataProcessor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var CustomerViewHelper
     */
    protected $customerViewHelper;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $dateTime;

    /**
     * @var ObjectFactory
     */
    protected $objectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter
     */
    protected $extensibleDataObjectConverter;

    /**
     * @var CustomerModel
     */
    protected $customerModel;

    /**
     * @var AuthenticationInterface
     */
    protected $authentication;

    /**
     * @var EmailNotificationInterface
     */
    private $emailNotification;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Backend
     */
    private $eavValidator;

    /**
     * @var CredentialsValidator
     */
    private $credentialsValidator;

    /**
     * @var DateTimeFactory
     */
    private $dateTimeFactory;

    /**
     * @var AccountConfirmation
     */
    private $accountConfirmation;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var AddressRegistry
     */
    private $addressRegistry;

    /**
     * @param CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Random $mathRandom
     * @param Validator $validator
     * @param ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService
     * @param CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry
     * @param PsrLogger $logger
     * @param Encryptor $encryptor
     * @param ConfigShare $configShare
     * @param StringHelper $stringHelper
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param CustomerViewHelper $customerViewHelper
     * @param DateTime $dateTime
     * @param CustomerModel $customerModel
     * @param ObjectFactory $objectFactory
     * @param ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     * @param CredentialsValidator|null $credentialsValidator
     * @param DateTimeFactory|null $dateTimeFactory
     * @param AccountConfirmation|null $accountConfirmation
     * @param SessionManagerInterface|null $sessionManager
     * @param SaveHandlerInterface|null $saveHandler
     * @param CollectionFactory|null $visitorCollectionFactory
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder|null $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param AddressRegistry|null $addressRegistry
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Random $mathRandom,
        Validator $validator,
        ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService,
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        PsrLogger $logger,
        Encryptor $encryptor,
        ConfigShare $configShare,
        StringHelper $stringHelper,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        Registry $registry,
        CustomerViewHelper $customerViewHelper,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        CustomerModel $customerModel,
        ObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        CredentialsValidator $credentialsValidator = null,
        DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory = null,
        AccountConfirmation $accountConfirmation = null,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager = null,
        SaveHandlerInterface $saveHandler = null,
        CollectionFactory $visitorCollectionFactory = null,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder = null,
        AddressRegistry $addressRegistry = null
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->validationResultsDataFactory = $validationResultsDataFactory;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->customerMetadataService = $customerMetadataService;
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
        $this->configShare = $configShare;
        $this->stringHelper = $stringHelper;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->customerViewHelper = $customerViewHelper;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
        $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
        $this->credentialsValidator =
            $credentialsValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CredentialsValidator::class);
        $this->dateTimeFactory = $dateTimeFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(DateTimeFactory::class);
        $this->accountConfirmation = $accountConfirmation ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(AccountConfirmation::class);
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SessionManagerInterface::class);
        $this->saveHandler = $saveHandler
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SaveHandlerInterface::class);
        $this->visitorCollectionFactory = $visitorCollectionFactory
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CollectionFactory::class);
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
        $this->addressRegistry = $addressRegistry
            ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(AddressRegistry::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get authentication
     *
     * @return AuthenticationInterface
     */
    private function getAuthentication()
    {
        if (!($this->authentication instanceof AuthenticationInterface)) {
            return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\AuthenticationInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->authentication;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resendConfirmation($email, $websiteId = null, $redirectUrl = '')
    {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email, $websiteId);
        if (!$customer->getConfirmation()) {
            throw new InvalidTransitionException(__("Confirmation isn't needed."));
        }

        try {
            $this->getEmailNotification()->newAccount(
                $customer,
                self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION,
                $redirectUrl,
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            );
        } catch (MailException $e) {
            // If we are not able to send a new account email, this should be ignored
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function activate($email, $confirmationKey)
    {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email);
        return $this->activateCustomer($customer, $confirmationKey);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function activateById($customerId, $confirmationKey)
    {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        return $this->activateCustomer($customer, $confirmationKey);
    }

    /**
     * Activate a customer account using a key that was sent in a confirmation email.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
     * @param string $confirmationKey
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InvalidTransitionException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InputMismatchException
     */
    private function activateCustomer($customer, $confirmationKey)
    {
        // check if customer is inactive
        if (!$customer->getConfirmation()) {
            throw new InvalidTransitionException(__('The account is already active.'));
        }

        if ($customer->getConfirmation() !== $confirmationKey) {
            throw new InputMismatchException(__('The confirmation token is invalid. Verify the token and try again.'));
        }

        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        // No need to validate customer and customer address while activating customer
        $this->setIgnoreValidationFlag($customer);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
        $this->getEmailNotification()->newAccount(
            $customer,
            'confirmed',
            '',
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        );
        return $customer;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function authenticate($username, $password)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }

        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        if ($this->getAuthentication()->isLocked($customerId)) {
            throw new UserLockedException(__('The account is locked.'));
        }
        try {
            $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $password);
            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Exceptions.ThrowCatch
        } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }
        if ($customer->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired($customer)) {
            throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__("This account isn't confirmed. Verify and try again."));
        }

        $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData($customer);
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'customer_customer_authenticated',
            ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $password]
        );

        $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $customer]);

        return $customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention what all steps you tried using preference/plugin.

Comment: @Abudul Pathan please refer to my updated question.

Comment: "but it start giving me an error when authenticate"
What error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\AccountManagement" />
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/AccountManagement.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;

/**
 * Handle various customer account actions
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CookieAndSessionMisuse)
 */
class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
{
    /**
     * @var AuthenticationInterface
     */
    protected $authentication;

    /**
     * @var CustomerFactory
     */
    private $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $eventManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Validator $validator
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share $configShare
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $stringHelper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $customerViewHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $objectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\CredentialsValidator|null $credentialsValidator
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Intl\DateTimeFactory|null $dateTimeFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountConfirmation|null $accountConfirmation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface|null $sessionManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface|null $saveHandler
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\CollectionFactory|null $visitorCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder|null $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressRegistry|null $addressRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ForgotPasswordToken\GetCustomerByToken|null $getByToken
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries|null $allowedCountriesReader
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Validator $validator,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share $configShare,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $stringHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $customerViewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\CredentialsValidator $credentialsValidator = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Intl\DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory = null,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountConfirmation $accountConfirmation = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface $saveHandler = null,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\CollectionFactory $visitorCollectionFactory = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder = null,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressRegistry $addressRegistry = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($customerFactory, $eventManager, $storeManager, $mathRandom, $validator, $validationResultsDataFactory, $addressRepository, $customerMetadataService, $customerRegistry, $logger, $encryptor, $configShare, $stringHelper, $customerRepository, $scopeConfig, $transportBuilder, $dataProcessor, $registry, $customerViewHelper, $dateTime, $customerModel, $objectFactory, $extensibleDataObjectConverter, $credentialsValidator, $dateTimeFactory, $accountConfirmation, $sessionManager, $saveHandler, $visitorCollectionFactory, $searchCriteriaBuilder, $addressRegistry);

        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get authentication
     *
     * @return AuthenticationInterface
     */
    private function getAuthentication()
    {
        if (!($this->authentication instanceof \Magento\customer\Model\AuthenticationInterface)) {
            return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\AuthenticationInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->authentication;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */    
    public function authenticate($username, $password)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }

        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        if ($this->getAuthentication()->isLocked($customerId)) {
            throw new UserLockedException(__('The account is locked.'));
        }
        try {
            $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $password);
        } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }
        if ($customer->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired($customer)) {
            throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__("This account isn't confirmed. Verify and try again."));
        }

        $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData($customer);
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'customer_customer_authenticated',
            ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $password]
        );

        $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $customer]);

        return $customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pratik Oza... Thanks for your correct answer. Extra parameter removed         (Public Function: \Magento\Customer\Model\ForgotPasswordToken\GetCustomerByToken $getByToken = null,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries $allowedCountriesReader = null) (Parent: $getByToken, $allowedCountriesReader)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create the constructor and call the parent constructor in your dependency injection attempt.

Comment: No... I didn't update the constructor in question due to long characters. Private $customerFactory, $customerRegistry, $addressRegistry, $Account confirmation. public function __construct( $customerFactory, $customerRegistry, $addressRegistry, $Account confirmation)

Comment: what do you mean you didn't update the constructor? You don't even have a constructor.

Comment: I do have the constructor inside my custom model. I just din't put in the question due to long characters

Comment: I've update my question in preference section

Comment: You don't call the parent constructor in your code and why do you override all methods?

Comment: Sorry... I'm not familiar with model overriding so I copy all and check which part do I miss. Let me try the parent call 1st.